# How to access the invocationId in SignalR core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-signalr, signalr-client

I'm creating an app with SignalR Core on Azure. Now I need to match the invoked request with the returned value and callback. I would like to use the `invocationId` to make sure the method that will be executed is the latest invoked request. To avoid as happens in the attached image.

```
var _this.latestInvokeId = ??
connection.invoke('getData', _this.ID)
    .then(function (data) {
        if(this.invocationId === _this.latestInvokeId)
            console.log('Use the data', data)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

When the `getData` is invoked multiple times in a short interval I would like to be sure to use the right response. So the response with `invocationId` 8 needs to be ignored and only the response with `invocationId` 9 is used.
[image]

Comment: Do you want to prevent from invoking/triggering `getData` method for a short interval 
 once it has been triggered? If you can clarify more about the actual scenario, we can understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a new id that is send on the request and can be validated when the value is returned.